# Some drupal database operations won't complete

Tags: drush, updating

On a development server (and it's sister staging server), I'm not sure how I got myself into this situation. When running `drush updatedb` I get this error below.

```
$ drush updatedb
The following updates are pending:

redirect module : 
  7101 -   Add status field. 
  7102 -   Disable redirects that could cause infinite loops. 

webform module : 
  7322 -   Add index on {webform_submitted_data}.data. 

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
Cannot add field redirect.status: field already exists.                                       [error]
Performed update: redirect_update_7101                                                        [ok]
Cannot add index data to table webform_submitted_data: index already exists.                  [error]
Performed update: webform_update_7322                                                         [ok]
Finished performing updates.
```

I occasionally dump the production server database onto dev and stage to have an updated copy.

Is there a way I can push through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is everything working fine on the production server?  If so, try erasing the development database, and then copy the production database over it again.  Drush sql-sync does not delete the target database by default.

```
drush @dev sql-create
drush sql-sync @prod @dev
```